# Apex Account to Contact set email

Tags: apex, email, account, contact

I'm trying to execute the code in the following test class:

```
static testMethod void testLeadStatusExistingDeal() {
Test.startTest();

Lead record = new Lead(LastName = 'Dimitrov', Company ='emp1', Monthly_Volume__c= '1234', Phone='1423542452', Website='www.google.com');
insert record;
System.debug('record ' + record);

Contact contact = new Contact(Company_Name__c = record.id, email = 'dylan@dylan.com');
Contact contact1 = new Contact(Company_Name__c = record.id, email = 'dilyan@dilyan.com');
insert contact;
insert contact1;

Account account = new Account(name = 'acc1');
insert account;
Merchant_To_Contact__c merchantToAccount = new Merchant_To_Contact__c(Merchant_Name__c = account.id, email__c = 'dylan@dylan.com');
Merchant_To_Contact__c merchantToAccount1 = new Merchant_To_Contact__c(Merchant_Name__c = account.id, email__c = 'dilyan@dilyan.com'); 

insert merchantToAccount;
insert merchantToAccount1;

ApexPages.StandardController c = new ApexPages.StandardController(record);
LeadToMerchantController ltmc = new LeadToMerchantController(c);
String leadStatusExistingDeal = ltmc.leadStatusExistingDeal(record);
System.debug('leadStatusExistingDeal ' + leadStatusExistingDeal);
Test.stopTest();
```

}

Instead I get the following error Field is not writeable: Merchant_To_Contact__c.Email__c

Could you please advise what am I doing wrong and how to execute this test class without such error?

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: I'm guessing that Email__c is a formula field. You'll need to update the record such that the formula is satisfied, probably by linking a contact to the record.

Comment: If the Email__c is of formula type is there a way to see what is the exact formula in order to find out which is the data source?

Comment: You can examine the describe results of the field, but that probably won't help you. I'd suggest using [recalculateFormulas](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_apex_new_classes_methods.htm) to have the formulas refresh. You still need to set up the appropriate parent record(s) though.

Comment: Hi,

Indeed the Email__c field in Merchant_To_Contact__c is a formula field.

Comment: [Please have look at the Email__c field screenshot](http://s22.postimg.org/5yg06poup/Email_c_field.png)

Comment: It is also a custom, filterable and nilable.

Could you please advise what I need to do next in order to avoid the following error 
Field is not writeable: Merchant_To_Contact__c.Email__c
I'd like to ask you to include some code example as well.